# Argument #1 must be of type Model, Pest\Mock\Mock given

Tags: laravel, phpunit, php-8, php-pest

I'm trying to write some tests using Pest and mocking my model.
I have a Repository that accepts two models, this is the definition:

```
class MyRepo
{
    public function __construct(private ModelA $modelA, private ModelB $modelB)
    {
      //
    }
}
```

Now in my test i created two mock for `ModelA` and `ModelB`, and created the repository:

```
$modelA = mock(ModelA::class);
$modelB = mock(ModelB::class);

$repo = new MyRepo($modelA, $modelB);
```

Running this code I get a check error like this:

```
__construct(): Argument #1 ($modelA) must be of type App\Models\ModelA, Pest\Mock\Mock given
```

If I remove the type check on Repository constructor, all works fine.

I tried to find a solution, but for now, I have had no luck. I'm not able to understand what i need to change to make it works

Comment: Why are you mocking a model ? is it literally a Laravel Model ? If so you NEVER mock a Laravel's Model but you use [Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-model-factories).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment states, don't mock models, this is not the intended use of the testing tools in `Laravel`. In other words, i have written thousands of tests and not once i had to mock the model.

Having Models as parameters to a constructor, wouldn't make sense. As `Laravels` container would often just resolve them to empty models, with `resolve(MyRepo::class);` and the container is an essential tool for Mocking.

With that said, the problem you are facing is, `mock()` returns the Pest Mock object and not the Mockery object, this object is located here on the [Pest Mock Class](https://github.com/pestphp/pest-plugin-mock/blob/c2dbca6cb85a870f2e666d01aca0a3fdca7d063c/src/Mock.php#L24). This can only be returned by [calling](https://github.com/pestphp/pest-plugin-mock/blob/c2dbca6cb85a870f2e666d01aca0a3fdca7d063c/src/Mock.php#L56) `expect()`. Therefor utilize `expect()`, with the operations you need to call on your mock and your code should work.

```
mock(ModelA::class)
    ->shouldReceive('update')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry but i'm new to mocking objects and i gets a little confused. What you mean with "Having Models as parameters to a constructor, wouldn't make sense" ?
I have those two models on constructor because it's the repository, in my app i never create those model, i use DI. Its wrong ?

Comment: Thats correct, i was afraid you wanted to inject concrete models into the consctrutor. Like new YourRepo(ModelA::find(1), ModelB::find(2));, thats incorrect, but if you use DI thats totally correct. It's often a thing people struggle with in mocking and testing, i thought the same here due to the code shown. But you are totally correct mate.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your answer now I changed my code using a factory, and I pass that factory to the repository. This is the right way?

The `getUser` is the method i want to test, so i create the two model with a factory. It's right ?

```
// prepare
$modelA = ModelA::factory()->create();
$modelB = ModelB::factory()->create();

$repository = new MyRepo($modelA, $modelB);
$service = new MyService($repository);

// act
$user = $service->getUser("fake");
```